# What does it mean to say "if n"?

Tags: python, if-statement

What does it mean to say `if n`? I don't get why `if n` works in an if statement. Shouldn't there be an argument such as `if n == 0` or something, not just `if n`?

```
def AddMusicAtPosition(self, newMusic, n):
    if n:
        self.nextMusic.AddMusicAtPosition(newMusic, n - 1)
    else:
        newMusic.nextMusic = self.nextMusic
        self.nextMusic = newMusic
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python, `if n` is equivalent to `if bool(n)`.

For integers, `bool(i)` equals to `i != 0`.

---

If `n` is an instance of a class, then

- if the class defines `__bool__`, then `n.__bool__()` is called
- if the class doesn't define `__bool__` but `__len__`, then `n.__len__() != 0` is evaluated
- if the class defines neither `__bool__` nor `__len__`, it always evaluates to True (think like `n is not None`).

Comment: "If n is a class object, then" isn't quite right. Perhaps "If n is an instance of a class, then"

Comment: @RoadRunner Well, I think the point was to avoid confusion with instances of `type` and its subclasses, which are objects that represent classes and thus could reasonably be called "class objects".

Answer (score 0):

Usually conditions are like:

```
if n==1:
```

But that evaluates to:

```
if True:
```

If the conditions is right, python in default everything is True, so the statement is passed, and since:

```
bool(n)
```

Could be `True` or `False` too, `n` could do it already, and the code will pass if `n` is True, don't pass if `n` is False, so that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Any value in Python can be tested for truth. As long as it's not `None`, `False`, zero, or empty; it is considered true. See more details in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

In your case the recursion should stop when `n` gets to zero as zero is not considered `True`. You can test this with:

```
if 0:
  print('zero is true') # won't be printed
else:
  print('zero is false') # will be printed
```

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say "As long as it's not None, False, zero, or empty; it is considered true", because that ignores all the custom types that define `__bool__()` or `__len__()`.

Comment: I was trying to keep it simple and not go too much over what the question actually asks. if `__len__()` returns 0, for example, you can arguably call it empty.

Comment: Yeah, that's reasonable, although it still ignores the case of `__bool__()`, which I think is a big enough exception that it's worth mentioning. The fact is, there are a lot of values which are not `None`, `False`, zero, nor could be considered "empty" in any meaningful sense, and yet are falsy because of their class's implementation of `__bool__()`. I completely agree with not getting into the details, I just think it's important to mention that what you've said doesn't apply to _all_ values.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, almost everything is True except False, None, 0 and Empty entities (string, list, sets, dictionary)!(Could have miss others)

So if you state that:

```
if n:
    print(True)
```

If n is not 0, False, None or Empty entities, then it would print True.

To test the values and behavior, you can do:

```
ns = [None, 0, False, '', {},(), [],1, True,]

for n in ns:
    if n:
        print(n, 'It is True')
    else:
        print(n, 'it is False')
```

So what happens is that if n, checks for truthfulness of value n :)